# Скачет скорость соединения через wifi на новом ноутбуке

Tags: windows, wifi, настройка

Купил новый ноутбук asus, стоит чистая windows 10, все нормально, но, 1) скорость wifi не превышает 20мбит/c из-за чего в торренте и т.п. вещах скорость загрузки файлов выше 2мб. не поднимается, так же заметил, что скорость соединения по wifi постоянно скачет [image]
Из-за чего играть в онлайн игры типа overwatch невозможно, что делать?

P.S. всевозможные штуки для экономии батареи я отключил, тестировал на 3-х сетях, и пробовал менять каналы на роутерах

Comment: Дрова стоят от Майков, Асуса или Квалкома? И на сколько они последние?

Comment: не знаю, в диспетчере есть два драйвера: 1) qualcomm версия 10.0.3.458 и 2) microsoft версия 10.0.17134.1

Comment: Стоп. 1 железка = 1 драйвер. Не знаешь - начни с выяснения чьи дрова.